# "Partial texts" feature in phpMyAdmin v4.0.5+ not working

Tags: phpmyadmin, config

The "Partial texts" feature in phpMyAdmin v4.0.5+ is not working for me anymore. I've tried to change some of the browse settings, but can't find a way. Having rows show Full Text all the time is really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this bug (fixed in 4.0.6) is related to your problem?
https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4066/

Also, does it happen for all tables or just some?

Comment: It sure seems to be talking about the same issue. I have to wait for the cPanel updates to include the 4.0.6 update, to be able to verify. I had checked the change log of 4.0.6, but didn't see that issue addressed. Fingers crossed.

Comment: ChangeLog entry is "bug #4066 varchar field not truncated in table browse mode".